# SonarQube MSBuild fails to exclude files

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am running an analysis using msbuild on debian, using the following command:

```
 mono /msbuild/SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /d:sonar.login=<sonarqubetoken> /d:sonar.host.url=https://<my-server> /d:sonar.exclusions=test/**/* /k:<my-project-key>
```

**However** in the `end` command:

```
INFO: Index files
INFO: Excluded sources: 
INFO:   test/**/*
INFO: 17 files indexed
INFO: 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
INFO: Excluded sources for coverage: 
INFO:   test/**
```

and the analysis on the UI of my server includes files from `test/` folder.

Why does it fail to ignore the specific files?

Using `SonarQube 6.7` and `sonar-scanner:3.3`

Comment: LGTM. It's definitely `test/` in the root and not `tests/` or `[space]test/`?

Comment: Also you're using `mono` so case sensitive file system?

Comment: the paths and the cases are correct ... no idea what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have managed to get around this situation is by adding the following line to the `.csproj` file of the projects I want excluded

```
<!-- Exclude the project from SonarQube analysis -->
<SonarQubeExclude>true</SonarQubeExclude>
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  SonarQube still processed the project.

Answer (score 1):

Exclusions are difficult to set correctly from the analysis side, as demonstrated by your attempt. Your best bet is to set these from the UI.

Comment: this is not very automatable or scalable. I would not consider this a solution for real companies with a large software footprint

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with after I upgraded to SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.2

As pkaramol stated and by looking at the docs [[1](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/appendix-2.md),[2](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/appendix-3.md)] this seems to be the only solution because sonar.exclusions matches only files in each project folder and not the solution folder. I wrote a python (>= 3.5) script for my CI which adds those lines to projects I want to be excluded.

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

SOURCEDIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

SQ_EXCLUDE_TAG = """
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Exclude the project from analysis -->
        <SonarQubeExclude>true</SonarQubeExclude>
    </PropertyGroup>
"""

def add_sq_exclude_tag(project_name):
    search_path = os.path.join(SOURCEDIR_PATH, '**', '{}.csproj'.format(project_name))
    for file_path in glob.iglob(search_path, recursive=True):
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
            lines = outfile.readlines()
            project_end_tag = lines[-1]
            lines[-1] = SQ_EXCLUDE_TAG
            lines.append(project_end_tag)
        with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
            outfile.writelines(lines)
        print('Added sonarqube exclude tag to {}'.format(file_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    add_sq_exclude_tag('*csprojFileConatainsThisString*')
    add_sq_exclude_tag('exactCsprojFileNameWithoutFileEnding')
```